# Facebook comments on 3rd-party sites

Tags: facebook, comments

The Detroit newspapers recently switched their post-article comments to the Facebook platform.

Reluctantly, I opened a Facebook account in order to be able to comment on these sites.  My comments show up (usually) on the website for ME -- I can see them -- but it's clear that nobody else is seeing the comments, as I have received no subsequent feedback (or "likes," for that matter) to my posts -- either positive or negative -- after commenting on 25+ articles.

I have absolutely no desire to use Facebook itself in any way, but would like my comments to appear on 3rd-party websites.  Am I missing something basic here?

Comment: Your comments might not be valuable enough for people to respond.

Comment: That cannot be possible. I'm a frequent user of the site 9gag and they also use the Facebook social plug-ins as their commenting platform. I have never had any problem with that. Log out of your Facebook account and just visit that site as a guest and see if your comments appear.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are being picked up as spam as all comments should be public (otherwise it defeats the purpose of the plugin)

> If you choose to share a comment in the comments box, that comment is public and visible to everyone on the Internet. This is consistent with how comments work on most public websites.
>
>   <sub>-- Facebook Help: [Who can see comments I make on other websites via the comment box plugin?](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=133528096721973#Who-can-see-comments-I-make-on-other-websites-via-the-comment-box-plugin?)</sub>

If you recently opened a Facebook account, have little or no connection on Facebook and commented recently on 25+ articles, then it definitely sounds like you are being caught by a spam filter of some sort or an admin banned you.

> Admins can also blacklist words and ban users. If a new comment is published from a banned user or contains a blacklisted word, this comment will automatically have limited visibility.

Consider showing an example Detroit post from which you commented on to see if any of the community users can reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

On Facebook go the the arrow next to home then privacy settings -> public.

> This setting will apply to status updates and photos you post to your
>   timeline from a Facebook app that doesn't have the inline audience
>   selector, like Facebook for Blackberry.